# Dynamic Tree Data table with SUM in Primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces

Hi I am trying to figure out Dynamic Tree Data table with SUM. My table structure is : nodeID, nodeName, parentID, level, balance;
I want to display the table as tree data table and when Node balance will be sum of his all child balance.
Suppose.....

nodeID, nodeName, parentID, level, balance

1 A 0 1 0.00

2 B 1 2 300.00

3 C 1 2 -20.00

4 D 1 2 250.00

5 E 4 3 220.00

6 F 4 3 250.00

7 G 5 4 230.00

8 H 0 1 150.00

9 I 8 2 350.00

In this scenario, there will be only two rows visible for the first time. Like bellow...

nodeID, nodeName, parentID, level, balance

- 1 A 0 1 1230 0.00
- 2 H 0 1 400.00

After this, when click + icon , child node of level 2 will display and similarly display.................................

Any idea please.

Comment: And the prblem is? [mcve]